# How can I divide the frequency of a factor by a fixed value in ggplot2 geom_bar?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to divide all the values of bars in a geom_bar by a fixed value, to display the average value/week

I have a list of attendance records, each showing the date, weekday, and the name of the error. I want to make a graph showing the average number of absences and tardy per weekday.

Simplified version of my data for reproducing:

```
df <- data.frame(

date = c(2019-01-01,2019-01-01,2019-01-01,2019-01-02,2019-01-02,2019-01-02,2019-01-08,2019-01-09),

weekday = c("Monday","Monday","Monday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Tuesday","Monday","Tuesday"),

name = c("absent","absent","tardy","absent","tardy","tardy","absent","absent")
)
```

Plotting what I have:

```
ggplot(df,aes(weekday)) + geom_bar(aes(fill = name))
```

This displays a plot showing the total number of absences and tardy on Monday and Tuesdays. 
What I want to do is divide the total number by 2(the number of weeks), to show the average number of absent and tardy on each weekday.

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Yes, this is the desired result. I hadn't thought of simply changing the axes labels.

Comment: Not directly about the question, but the data you posted here is likely not the data you're using. Dates won't come through as `2019-01-01` without quotation marks—what you're doing here is subtracting 2019 - 1 - 1, which is obviously 2017, not the date 2019-01-01

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the axis values without changing the data using the `labels` argument of `scale_y_continuous`

```
ggplot(df,aes(weekday)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = name)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) x/2)
```